# how to assign two 2d array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I have written a program which make a 2d array and then set its numbers.
The second step that I have problem in it is that when I want to shift rows and columns I face with a problem in this line `nmatrix[i*c+j] = 0;`

the error is this : `error: incompatible types in assignment of 'int' to 'int [(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)(c + shiftc)) + -1)) + 1)]'`

here is the code :

```
void shiftMatrix(int *matrix, int r,int c ,int shiftr,int shiftc){
int nmatrix [r+shiftr][c+shiftc];
for(int i = 0; i< shiftr; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j<shiftc;j++)
    {
        nmatrix[i*c+j] = 0;
    }
}
for(int i = shiftr; i< r; i++)
{
    for(int j = shiftc; j<c;j++)
    {
        nmatrix[i*c+j] = matrix[i*c+j];
    }
}
}
```

Any help please??
thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/936687/356440

Comment: Do you want to shift rows and columns, or will it be enough to shift only rows? (this is very important for choosing the solution)

Comment: I want to be able to shift both of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int nmatrix [r+shiftr][c+shiftc];
```

First of all, you are using an array with non-constant bounds, which is a [controversial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947378/c-why-does-int-arraysize-work) feature.

In addition, here you are declaring a two-dimensional array `nmatrix`, but your other matrix (`matrix`) is a pointer to `int` (or a one-dimensional array, if you like to look at it this way). This is a recipe for confusion.

You can easily declare `nmatrix` ("new matrix"?) as a one-dimensional array:

```
int nmatrix[(r+shiftr) * (c+shiftc)];
```

Or (presumably better)

```
std::vector<int> nmatrix((r+shiftr) * (c+shiftc));
```

Then, your code `nmatrix[i*c+j] = 0` will work (however, you have to change `c` to `c+shiftc` whenever you work with `nmatrix`).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define an array dynamically the way you do it.
You need to use the c++ keyword `new`:

```
int nmatrix[][]  = new int [r+shiftr][c+shiftc];
```

You cannot define arrays the way you did, with non constant int value for dimension, because such static arrays are to be defined for *memory* at the compile stage. Thus dimensions should be const expression.

On the contrary with keyword `new` you can define dimensions for arrays at run-time stage, because it's dynamic allocation.

There are more detailed answers in this SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/936687/356440).

Comment: It doesn't work unfortunately. I have created 2d arrays in this way.

Comment: the first Error: error: declaration of 'nmatrix' as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first|

Comment: The second Error:error: 'c' cannot appear in a constant-expression|

Comment: First step, learn how to make simple 1-D dynamic array. cf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029870/c-how-to-create-a-dynamic-array-of-integers

Comment: I made a typo mistake in my answer; it's `int nmatrix[][]` instead of `int [][]nmatrix`. Sorry

Comment: You can find more information in this question about* dynamic multidimensionnal arrays* http://stackoverflow.com/q/936687/356440